# Clone a repository during deployment on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I have a Rails project **PROJECTX**, which is hosted on Heroku. For storing production configs and files, I am using a different repository **PROJECTX-config**. Is it possible to:

1. clone PROJECTX-config,
2. remove current config files, and
3. symlink config files to PROJECTX-config files

Note that this has to be done on Heroku. Also I am aware that Heroku has options to maintain configs using environment variables, but this is not what I am looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: No - use env vars instead. Heroku has an ephemeral file system so you cannot symlink to other repositories.

Comment: @max I can't use enviroment variables for all config. Also I believe that app config should not be present in envoroment variables, as it is tedious to maintain rather than maintaining a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible.

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the
>   most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running
>   processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no
>   files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and
>   any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or
>   restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to
>   application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal
>   dyno management.
>   - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Or at least not without a Rube Goldberg machine like setupe where you setup some kind of automation (like a post-commit hook) to merge repo A and repo B and push the result to heroku.

> Also I believe that app config should not be present in environment variables, as it is tedious to maintain rather than maintaining a file.

Heroku does not agree here.

> The traditional approach for handling such config vars is to put them
>   under source - in a properties file of some sort. This is an
>   error-prone process, and is especially complicated for open source
>   apps which often have to maintain separate (and private) branches with
>   app-specific configurations.
>   A better solution is to use environment
>   variables, and keep the keys out of the code. On a traditional host or
>   working locally you can set environment vars in your bashrc file. On
>   Heroku, you use config vars.
>   - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Although you might be overestimating what you actually need to store in ENV vars. You only need to store secrets such as API keys in ENV.

Other non-secret configuration such your settings for various gems can and should be setup in `config/initializers`.

If you still think using the GUI is that terrible then use YAML files which you parse and use to set the ENV vars:

```
require 'yaml'

yaml = YAML.load_file(File.join(__dir__, 'conf.yml'))

def create_key(*components)
  components.join('_').upcase
end

env_vars = yaml["production"].each_with_object({}) do |(key,value), memo|
  key_components = [key]
  if value.kind_of? Hash
    value.each_pair do |k,v|
      memo[create_key(*key_components.dup.push(k))] = v
    end
  else
    memo[create_key(*key_components)] = value
  end
end.each do |k,v|
  system("heroku config:set #{k}=#{v}")
  puts "Setting #{k} = #{v}; #{ $? }"
end
```

Or you could even store a serialized form (JSON or YAML) in a single env var - there is a total size limit of 32kb though.